# How to select a JSON array to a table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Is it possible to output a nested array into a table?

I intend to loop over the orders array and capture the line_item id's for the current iteration.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000) = N'
{
  "orders":[
    {
      "id":123,
      "line_items":[
        {
          "id":1
        },
        {
          "id":2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};'

SELECT
  [LineId]
FROM OPENJSON (@json, '$.orders.line_items') WITH (
  [LineId] BIGINT '$.id'
);
```

Desired output

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Comment: If the orders array contains a single object:  `OPENJSON (@json, '$.orders[0].line_items') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working option using a CROSS APPLY to extract the array.

```
SELECT id = JSON_VALUE(B.Value,'$.id')
 FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.orders') A
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (A.value, '$.line_items') as B
```

**Results**

```
id
1
2
```

Comment: This is great and seems to be what I need, thank you. Is it possible to filter on the current order.id iteration? e.g where id = 123

Comment: Just add ` where JSON_VALUE(A.Value,'$.id') = 123` at the end

Comment: Ha. I have been looking at this json so long I forgot how to basic. You're a legend and a gent thank you sir.